# How to change a default drop down icon of select list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any code or site which will provide me a source code for custom select

I want to use a image in in place of default dropdown icon..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done with normal HTML or CSS, I've tried also.

You might find this useful: [jQuery custom select boxes](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/).

Really easy to implement and you can style the select boxes any way you want.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take this jQuery Combo:
http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Nope, can't be done with normal HTML `<select>` elements.

You would have to resort to a JavaScript-driven alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The [Uniform plugin](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) for jQuery is quite nice for this; it let's you style the select drop down form element as well as check boxes and radio buttons. It's worth a look.